# ASP.NET MVC How to include css from database

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc

I have HTML & CSS stored in different columns in a database row. I can use `@Html.Raw(string)` to render my HTML, but how can I include the css style?

Comment: how the data store look like, any sample will be great

Comment: Not sure the datastore design is relevant here, rather how to get a `string` to render out as CSS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@Html.Raw(string s)` simply renders the provided string as an `IHtmlString` in the view. All you need to do is provide it in a tag that can understand the rendered contents.

```
<style type="text/css>
    @Html.Raw(style)
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer